# How to get the position of tf frame

Tags: rviz, moveit, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to get the position of the tf frame (child frame in rviz) , when I use `tf.TransformListener().lookupTransform(parent_link, child_link, rospy.Time())` I get the relative position and relative orientation and not position and orientation, how to get the position and orientation using python script?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414962/how-to-get-the-position-of-tf-frame/) by [TapleFlib](https://answers.ros.org/users/144407/tapleflib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2023-05-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All positions are measured relative to some reference frame. I believe that the rviz display is showing the position compared to your configured 'world' frame setting. And the position relative to the parent.

If you call `lookupTransform(parent_link, child_link, Time(0))` You're explicitly asking for the transform between `parent` and `child`.

You wan to use `lookupTransform(world_frame, child_link, TIme(0))` to get the latest transform from the world frame to the child link which I think is what you're considering non-relative position. You have to pick your reference to be able to do that.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TapleFlib](https://answers.ros.org/users/144407/tapleflib/) on 2023-05-09**:
Got it thanks so much !